# Delete key:value pair from dict in list in nested dict

Tags: python, dpath

Lets say I have this dict:

```
dictos = {
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": 3,
            "d": 4,
            "e": [],
            "f": [{"g": 5}, 'test', {"h": 6, "i": 7}]
        }
    }
}
```

And lets say I want to delete "c": 3 pair. What I am doing:

```
import dpath.util
path = "a/b/c"
dpath.util.delete(dictos, path)
```

It is working great. The output is:

```
{
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'd': 4,
      'e': [],
      'f': [{'g': 5}, 'test', {'h': 6, 'i': 7}]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when I am trying to delete key:value pair inside the list.
Lets say I want to delete "h":6. So when doing:

```
path = "a/b/f[2]/h"
dpath.util.delete(dictos, path)
```

I am getting:

> dpath.exceptions.PathNotFound: Could not find a/b/f[2]/h to delete
> it.

So the question basically is how to delete items from nested dicts that are in a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the library expects the same separator to be used for all segments i.e. use `a/b/f/2/h`

```
path = "a/b/f/2/h"
dpath.util.delete(dictos, path)
print(dictos)
```

Result:

```
{'a': {'b': {'d': 4, 'e': [], 'f': [{'g': 5}, 'test', {'i': 7}]}}}
```

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds, good answer. Here is a resource about the usage of indices etc: https://pypi.org/project/dpath/

Comment: The github README also has the usage docs: https://github.com/dpath-maintainers/dpath-python